# SQL Server How To make A Group Inside A Group - Using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I Have A Table has This Structure

[image]

```
EmployeeID | LogDate | LogTime | TerminalID | InOut | Accepted
```

This Table handle all of the Attending of the Employees

> Where InOut Column = 0 --> In (The Employee Just Punch In To Start His
>   Shift)
>
> Where Inout Column = 1 --> Out (The Employee Just Punch Out To
>   End His Shift)

Sample Of Date When i Make A Select 
[image]

for Example the previous image has EmployeeID = 1009
have 2 punches at 2015-10-14 (06:56:28) And (16:13:51)
i need in the Result to give me the Time He Attend between these two 2 Times
which is (09:17:23)

I want to have This Structure of Result

> ```
> EmployeeID | LogDate | NumberOfPunshings | State | HoursAttending
> ```

I Tried This Query

```
       select
Employeeid as EmpID,
logdate as logdt,
count(accepted) NumberOfPunshings,
case    count(accepted)                    WHEN 1 THEN 'No Out Punch'
                                           WHEN 2 THEN 'Perfect'
                                           Else 'Null'
                                           End as State,
CONVERT(varchar(12),
       DATEADD(minute,
       DATEDIFF(minute,
       (select top 1 LogTime from Accesslog where Inout=0),
       (select top 1 LogTime from Accesslog where InOut=1)), 0), 114) as HoursAttending

from Accesslog
where Logdate = CAST('2015-10-14' AS datetime)
group by
employeeid,logdate
order by Employeeid
```

But It's Not Working As I WANT it's only take one First value (of the Table) in HoursAttending

[image]

---

I've Create SQL Fiddle to Show you how the Data it Looks Like

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0152f9/1

```
EmpID |           logdt           |  NumberOfPunshings   |  State   |  HoursAttending
```

---

```
1009  | October, 14 2015 00:00:00 |          2           | Perfect  |   08:00:00:000
1088  | October, 15 2015 00:00:00 |          2           | Perfect  |   08:00:00:000
```

***the Expected Result Must be***

```
EmpID |           logdt           |  NumberOfPunshings   |  State   |  HoursAttending
```

---

```
1009  | October, 14 2015 00:00:00 |          2           | Perfect  |   08:00:00:000
1088  | October, 15 2015 00:00:00 |          2           | Perfect  |   06:00:00:000
```

The differences in these tables in HoursAttending Column because

> the first Employee (1009) start working from 08:00 to 16:00 so the
>   duration is (08:00) Correct.
>
> the Second Employee (1088) start working from 009:00 to 15:00 so the
>   duration is must be (06:00) not (08:00) Correct.

Comment: what do you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: @vkp i mean that the HoursAttending Column Only Take one value in each Rows. i will update the post with picture of result

Comment: You are not referencing EmpID in subquery

Comment: You need to provide both sample data and expected result. Showing us a failed result and partial data in images does not help provide an answer.

Comment: @Horaciux , i know that, but when i try to do that it gives Me 'Invalid column name 'empID'.
'

Comment: @Used_By_Already Ok, I've Update the Post, hope that be clear Now.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Is The Post Clear Now ?

Comment: @Horaciux How Can i reference the EmpID in the Subquery ?

Comment: @vkp is the Post Clear NOW ?

Comment: @Loai the use of images of data is just pure frustration for us, why not just give us the data in a reusable form? Then there is the "expected result" this need to be the FINAL and the EXPECTED result of the query, You probably have to create it manually. Perhaps you could create a small http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: @Used_By_Already Thanks, I've Update The Post, and Here is the SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0152f9/1. Hope this Much Clearer Now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine what would be possible if the data was made easily available to us, and we clearly understood what the expected final result should look like.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9fcd/4)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Accesslog
    ([EmployeeID] int, [LogDate] datetime, [LogTime] datetime, [Terminal] varchar(11), [InOut] int, [Accepted] int)
;

INSERT INTO Accesslog
    ([EmployeeID], [LogDate], [LogTime], [Terminal], [InOut], [Accepted])
VALUES
    (1009, '2015-10-14 00:00:00', '1900-01-01 06:36:06', 'abcdedghijk', 0, 1),
    (1009, '2015-10-14 00:00:00', '1900-01-01 16:22:41', 'abcdedghijk', 1, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
        EmployeeID
      , LogDate
      , MIN(case when InOut = 0 then cast(LogTime as time) end) as LogTimeMin
      , MAX(case when InOut = 1 then cast(LogTime as time) end) as LogTimeMax
      , COUNT(*) as CountPunches
      , CONVERT(varchar(12),
         DATEADD(minute,
         DATEDIFF(minute,
         MIN(case when InOut = 0 then cast(LogTime as time) end),
         MAX(case when InOut = 1 then cast(LogTime as time) end)), 0), 114) as HoursAttending
from Accesslog
group by
        EmployeeID
      , LogDate
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9fcd/4/0)**:

```
| EmployeeID |          LogDate |  LogTimeMin |  LogTimeMax | CountPunches | HoursAttending |
|------------|------------------|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------------|
|       1009 | October, 14 2015 | 06:36:06.00 | 16:22:41.00 |            2 |   09:46:00:000 |
```

**PART 2**

To address the issue of shifts, please try the following. Note if you THEN want only one row per day, use a group by query as well but making the query seen below into a "derived table" (subquery)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9fcd/4)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Accesslog
    ([EmployeeID] int, [LogDate] datetime, [LogTime] datetime, [Terminal] varchar(11), [InOut] int, [Accepted] int)
;

INSERT INTO Accesslog
    ([EmployeeID], [LogDate], [LogTime], [Terminal], [InOut], [Accepted])
VALUES
    (1209, '2015-10-14 00:00:00', '1900-01-01 07:00:00', 'abcdedghijk', 0, 1),
    (1209, '2015-10-14 00:00:00', '1900-01-01 12:01:00', 'abcdedghijk', 1, 1),
    (1209, '2015-10-14 00:00:00', '1900-01-01 15:00:00', 'abcdedghijk', 0, 1),
    (1209, '2015-10-14 00:00:00', '1900-01-01 20:02:00', 'abcdedghijk', 1, 1),
    (1009, '2015-10-14 00:00:00', '1900-01-01 08:00:00', 'abcdedghijk', 0, 1),
    (1009, '2015-10-14 00:00:00', '1900-01-01 16:00:00', 'abcdedghijk', 1, 1),
    (1088, '2015-10-15 00:00:00', '1900-01-01 09:00:00', 'aaaa', 0, 1),
    (1088, '2015-10-15 00:00:00', '1900-01-01 15:00:00', 'aaaa', 1, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
/*
 including (07:00 - 12:00) shift two (15:00 - 20:00) 
 */

WITH CTE as (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID, LogDate, InOut
                                    ORDER BY LogTime ASC) AS shiftno
        FROM Accesslog
             )
SELECT
        ins.EmployeeID
      , ins.LogDate
      , ins.LogTime  as LogTimeIn
      , outs.LogTime as LogTimeOut
      , ins.Accepted + ISNULL(outs.Accepted,0) as CountPunches
      , CONVERT(varchar(12),
         DATEADD(minute,
         DATEDIFF(minute,
         ins.LogTime,
         outs.LogTime), 0), 114) as HoursAttending
FROM CTE  AS ins
INNER JOIN CTE AS outs ON ins.InOut = 0 AND outs.InOut = 1
                      AND ins.EmployeeID = outs.EmployeeID
                      AND ins.LogDate = outs.LogDate
                      AND ins.shiftno = outs.shiftno
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9fcd/4/0)**:

```
| EmployeeID |                   LogDate |                 LogTimeIn |                LogTimeOut | CountPunches | HoursAttending |
|------------|---------------------------|---------------------------|---------------------------|--------------|----------------|
|       1009 | October, 14 2015 00:00:00 | January, 01 1900 08:00:00 | January, 01 1900 16:00:00 |            2 |   08:00:00:000 |
|       1088 | October, 15 2015 00:00:00 | January, 01 1900 09:00:00 | January, 01 1900 15:00:00 |            2 |   06:00:00:000 |
|       1209 | October, 14 2015 00:00:00 | January, 01 1900 07:00:00 | January, 01 1900 12:01:00 |            2 |   05:01:00:000 |
|       1209 | October, 14 2015 00:00:00 | January, 01 1900 15:00:00 | January, 01 1900 20:02:00 |            2 |   05:02:00:000 |
```

Comment: Thanks I've Update the post and here is the SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0152f9/1

Comment: Excellent. You have provided some data. Thanks. As the expected result ihas not been supplied I dont know if what i have done so far is correct or not.  So instead of guessing what it is you expect, i will stop.

Comment: Thanks, That's What I need Exactly, Now there is another Issue in the Query if you don't mind

Comment: What issue? This i cannot guess.

Comment: Lol, Actually some employees has more than 2 punches per day for example employees who have 2 shift per day how can i calculate the duration in each shift and sum it together, for example shift one (07:00 - 12:00) shift two (15:00 - 20:00) so the first Shift (05:00) and the second shift is (05:00) so the total will be (10:00)

Comment: how does one identify a shift? (i.e. is there a existing method, or specific data, for doing this?) plus 1: **sample data** and 2: **expected result** e.g. does your sqlfiddle contain such a test case? and if it does what is the expected result from that test case? (please don't describe the expected result, actually provide it as part of the question)

Comment: the second row in the hours attending must be 09:00 not 13:00 because of the two shift.

first shift start from (07:00 - 12:00) and second one (16:00 - 20:00) 

hope this will be clear :]

Comment: what is clear is that you don't understand the importance of "sample data" which covers ALL your test cases .... this is your question and the data is yours (not mine) you have a whole table of data to call on. so you should provide that sample data. Then, do NOT "describe" the "expected result"... actually take some data and figure out what the result should be and present that in the way you want the query to work.Then have a way to figure out if our query is correct or not. Please read: Short, Self Contained, Correct Example http://sscce.org/